# Use CONTAINS search with special characters like ampersand

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to use CONTAINS search with ampersand symbol but i can find although there are data in in table. How can i use it, is there any remedy?

E.g.:

```
DECLARE @Author NVARCHAR(200) = N'&'

SET @Author = '"' + REPLACE(@Author, ' ', '*" and "') + '*"'

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Taxonomy AS t (NOLOCK)
WHERE  CONTAINS(t.Author, @Author)
```

but returns no result :(

Comment: Except that LIKE.. Thanks

Comment: is your `Replace` funcion right? you are only replacing a blank space with the replacement... and in the example there is no blank space in `@Author`

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DECLARE @Author NVARCHAR(200) = N'"&"'

SET @Author = '"' + REPLACE(@Author, ' ', '*" and "') + '*"'

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Taxonomy AS t (NOLOCK)
WHERE  CONTAINS(t.Author, @Author)
```